# Matrix reduction for large data set to solve linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, octave

I've got a large set of linear equations at work to try to solve. These could be 200-300 rows of linear equations and 100-150 variables. Some of these variables won't be solvable, ie the linear equations that I have isn't enough to provide a solution.

Is there any existing software that I could use to help reduce the linear equations into a set of solvable equations? I'm thinking some form of matrix reduction but my engineering maths from 20 years ago isn't good enough to think of a solution.

I've just installed GNU Octave, so would be great too if someone could point me to the right direction on the above problem using GNU Octave.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have more equations than variables use a Penrose pseudo-inverse to find a least-squares solution. How you do it, doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks John. I haven't heard of Penrose pseudo-inverse. Let me dig around a bit more to see how it works.

Comment: Ask your company to hire a mathematical consultant.

Comment: Gerry, agree maybe that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Julia` language interface as a matrix calculator

```
A = rand(300,100)
b = rand(300)
x = A\b
```

and you get a solution that is equivalent to

```
x = inv(A'*A)*A'*b
```

where `A'` is the transpose of `A`, and the `inv()` function inverts a matrix

Mathematically the above solution to $Ax=b$ corresponds to the Penrose pseudo-inverse, also known as the least squares fit.

$$ x = \left(A^\intercal A \right)^{-1} A^\intercal b $$

Looking at the [GNU Octave website](https://octave.org/), it has a very similar syntax for solving a linear system of equations. I don't know if it will do the least squares thing automatically like `Julia` does.

> [image: fig1]

Comment: @PTh - Did you make any progress with your problem?

Comment: No, not yet. I didn't have time to look at this in detail. Hoping to have some time over the next few days to see if my rusty maths can get me there.